# Multiplying two data sets with different x-axis increments (Python)

Tags: python, data-fitting

I have two sets of experimental data, one for radiation as a function of time and one for transmission as a function of time. I would like to multiply these two data sets together, and plot radiation*transmission as a function of time. However, the problem is that the time increments between each 'radiation' datapoint and the time increments between each 'transmission' datapoint are not the same. To make things worse, the time increments are random.

Here are images of the two data sets I want to multiply together:
[Dataset 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX8qR.png)
[Dataset 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR1oS.png)

I am thinking of fitting a function to one of the datasets, but I do not know how, since fitting a function would require knowledge of the form of the function and the parameters, but I do not really know that for this experimental data.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: assume for a moment the time interval is known. if a graph were plotted what basic shape are we expecting for each(linear, x^2 , sinusoidal ,).  ?

Comment: @IGotThis I've just edited the post with a link to images of the two data sets. As you can see, there's really no underlying basic function for the data.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you already realize that a guaranteed exact solution is not possible, as you don't have compatible data points.  I recommend that you do this with some sort of interpolation mechanism, such as fitting a cubic spline to each data set.

A cubic spline is a shifting window of cubic functions, using a different cubic function for each set of four consecutive data points, weighting the interpolation function as a combination of the overlapping cubic functions for that interval.

Whatever method you choose, you will get two interpolation functions, f1(x) and f2(x), one for each data set.  Let X be the set of *all* x-coordinates, the union of the two data sets.  Your resulting data set will be simply f1(X) * f2(X).  Effectively, this uses the give data values where they exist, imputing interpolated values where they do not.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Thanks. I get a general idea of what you're trying to say. A bit confused about this part: "weighting the interpolation function as a combination of the overlapping cubic functions for that interval." I will try to look into the specific details of how to do this, and I'll post a question if I get stuck. Thanks!

Comment: I gave only the high points, because Stack Overflow is not a replacement for existing documentation.  Yes, post a question if you get stuck in the implementation.  Do remember to follow the posting standards if you do so: provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Mammoth Python has [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) implemented to handle this type of problem.